# How is the root-mean-square error related to the confidence interval?

Tags: mathematics, error-analysis, speed, statistics

If the car's speed is calculated as V = 100 km/s, and the RMSE of V is 20 km/s. 
Does that mean V = 100 +/- 10 km/s, or V = 100 +/- 20 km/s?

Comment: Do you know the formula of the RMSE? Furthermore, there is not such thing as **the** confidence interval.

Comment: @Semoi, yes I know the formula of RMSE. I mean how can I represent the RMSE value in terms of plus or minus notation? 
Is it the whole number of the half of it? 
(i.e., RMSE = 20, does it mean +/- 20 or +/- 10). 

[link](https://www.includehelp.com/ml-ai/Images/rmse-1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard notation is $\bar{x} \pm \sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation (=RMSE). In contrast, the 95% confidence interval is denoted as **not** $[\bar{x} - 2 \sigma, \bar{x} + 2 \sigma]$. These notations implicitly assumes that we have a symmetric error distribution, e.g. Gaussian.

Comment: So that means in the case of my example, V = 100 +/- RMSE. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit more complicated than that. 
$$
RMSE=\sqrt{E[\frac{1}{N}\sum_i{(y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}]}
$$
with $\hat{y}_i$ the "real/reference" value, and $y_i$ the measured value at instance $i$.
When you write this in terms of the variance and mean you end up with:
$$
RMSE=\sqrt{\sigma^2 + \mu^2}.
$$
Quite often the mean $\mu$ will be zero, in which case you end up with $RMSE=\sigma$. So if you want a $2\sigma$ CI (under the assumption your errors are Gaussian distributed), you will have $100 \pm 2\cdot RMSE$ km/s.

Comment: Excuse me what does 2(std) CI mean here?

Comment: A Confidence interval of 2$\sigma$. Also known as a 95% interval (in case you have a Gaussian distributed error)